# Elegant way for do ... while in groovy

Tags: loops, groovy, do-while

How to do code something like this in `groovy`?

```
do {

  x.doIt()

} while (!x.isFinished())
```

Because there is *no `do ... while` syntax* in groovy.

> **No 'do ... while()' syntax as yet.**
>
> Due to ambiguity, we've not yet added support for do .. while to Groovy

References:

- [groovy - dev](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/) > [do while](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/do-while-td4981923.html)
- [Migration From Classic to JSR syntax](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Migration+From+Classic+to+JSR+syntax?print=1)
- [Groovy Documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html) > [Control Structures](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_control_structures) >  [Looping](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_looping_structures)
- [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) > [Loops/Do-while Groovy](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/Do-while#Groovy)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is the closest it can get to purely language syntax based *do-while* in Groovy:

```
while ({
    x.doIt()
    !x.isFinished()
}()) continue
```

The last statement within curly braces (within closure) is evaluated as a loop exit condition.

Instead of `continue` keyword a semicolon can be used.

Additional nice thing about it, loop can be parametrized (kind of), like:

```
Closure<Boolean> somethingToDo = { foo ->
    foo.doIt()
    !foo.isFinished()
}
```

and then elsewhere:

```
while (somethingToDo(x)) continue
```

---

Formerly I've proposed this answer over here: [How do I iterate over all bytes in an inputStream using Groovy, given that it lacks a do-while statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188641/do-while-in-groovy-with-inputstream/22057667#22057667)

Comment: It has quite an unfortunate amount of brackets and braces but is the most elegant way anyway, without any repetitions.

Comment: Though I like the elegance and cleverness of this solution, I'm not happy with the readability. For myself I could imagine coming back to this code after a year and thinking "what is happening here". I'm undecided, because I don't like repetition either.

Answer (score 65):

You can roll your own looping that's almost what you want. 
Here's an example with `loop { code } until { condition }`
You can't have a corresponding `loop { code } while { condition }` because while is a keyword.
But you could call it something else.

Anyway here's some rough and ready code for loop until.
One gotcha is you need to use braces for the until condition to make it a closure.
There may well be other issues with it.

```
class Looper {
   private Closure code

   static Looper loop( Closure code ) {
      new Looper(code:code)
   }

   void until( Closure test ) {
      code()
      while (!test()) {
         code()
      }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
import static Looper.*

int i = 0
loop {
   println("Looping : "  + i)
   i += 1
} until { i == 5 }
```

Comment: Could not understand code of the usage, could you please eloborate? My understand is that everything after loop is considered as closure, and how until is called?

Comment: @Rao Think of it as `loop({...}).until({...})`. So `until()` is called on the return value of `loop()`. Groovy command expressions mean you can leave out the `.` in front of `until()`.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook, thank you so much for your explanation. It is clean now.

Answer (score 30):

Depending on your use case, there are options like this: [do .. while() in Groovy with inputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188641/do-while-in-groovy)

Or you can do:

```
x.doIt()
while( !x.finished ) { x.doIt() }
```

Or

```
while( true ) {
    x.doIt()
    if( x.finished ) break
}
```

Comment: Tim's second option (after the 'Or') - how much more standard of a break can there be?

Comment: After second look I think second option is simple and nice

Answer (score 10):

You can use a condition variable with the regular while loop:

```
def keepGoing = true
while( keepGoing ){
    doSomething()
    keepGoing = ... // evaluate the loop condition here
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Update** Groovy 2.6 has been abandoned to concentrate on 3.0.

From Groovy 2.6 on, do-while is supported when enabling the new Parrot Parser, from Groovy 3.0 on this is the default. See [release notes](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.6.html):

```
// classic Java-style do..while loop
def count = 5
def fact = 1
do {
    fact *= count--
} while(count > 1)
assert fact == 120
```

Comment: Too bad Groovy 2.6 was abandoned...I would not recommend people use a beta version of 2.6 that will never be released

Comment: You're right, thanks for the comment, I updated the answer!

Answer (score 3):

By now, Groovy has support for [`do/while`](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_do_while_loop):

```
do {

  x.doIt()

} while (!x.isFinished())
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can implement it in a Groovier way  :

```
def loop(Closure g){
    def valueHolder = [:]
    g.delegate = valueHolder
    g.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    g()
    [until:{Closure w ->
        w.delegate = valueHolder
        w.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        while(!w()){
        g()
        }
        }]
}
```