# Can Groovy do everything Java can?

Tags: java, groovy

I tend to think that Groovy is a super-set of Java... But I would like to hear opinions of more seasoned developers.

Is there anything that you can do in Java, but not in Groovy?

Java EE specs are fairly complex and maybe some of them are not accessible via Groovy?

Comment: As Will mentioned, here is something in place of [do..while](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20921949/2051952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`do { ... } while()`](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/do-while-td4981923.html) comes to mind. You can emulate it using closures or whatever.

...

We are currently working on a Java EE 6 coded mostly in Groovy. No problems whatsoever. CDI, transactions, jsf's managed beans, all work flawlessly. Of course we are kinda restricted when it comes to metaprogramming, so we usually use it for tests, mocks and when there are only groovy objects talking.

Comment: Encapsulation and inheritance can get a little freaky also

Comment: @tim_yates with `@CompileStatic` as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything with Groovy you can do with Java. The only complication is when you want the two to interact.

You can also use all the popular frameworks like Spring. In fact, Spring even lets you configure your beans with a [Groovy bean definition DSL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_groovy_bean_definition_dsl).