# Jenkins and Groovy and Regex

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am very new to using groovy.  Especially when it comes to Jenkins+Groovy+Pipelines.

I have a string variable that can change from time to time and want to apply a regex to accomodate the 2 or 3 possible results the string may return.

In my groovy code I have:

```
r = "Some text that will always end in either running, stopped, starting."
def regex = ~/(.*)running(.*)/
assert regex.matches(r)
```

But I receive an error in the jenkins output:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.regex.Pattern.matches() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

UPDATE:
I was able to create a pretty nifty jenking groovy while loop in a pipeline job i am creating to wait for a remote process using the regex info here and a tip in a different post ([How do I iterate over all bytes in an inputStream using Groovy, given that it lacks a do-while statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8188641/1741264)).

```
            while({
                def r = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'ssh "Insert your remote ssh command that returns text'
                println "Process still running.  Waiting on Stop"
                println "Status returned: $r"
                r =~ /running|starting|partial/
            }());
```

Comment: I ended up taking out the 'assert' line and just doing 'r =~ /running|starting|stopped/' thanks @injecteer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Straight-forward would be:

```
String r = "Some text that will always end in either running, stopped, starting."
assert r =~ /(.*)running(.*)/
```

Comment: Does assert always return TRUE whether it finds a match or not?

Comment: `assert` should never be returned in production code. it's usually used in the beginning to check prerequisites

Comment: what would be the best approach to take action on whether or not there is a match (for example entering and then breaking a while loop)?

Comment: you do either good'ol javas `break` or `return`, or use groovy collection methods, like `find()` or `grep()`

Comment: @injecteer how to get a matched string?

Comment: @Karthi see `eachMatch()` http://delineneo.com/2011/01/simple-regex-and-closure-example-in-groovy/

Answer (score 5):

If you are only using this regex here you can try the following:

```
r = "Some text that will always end in either running, stopped, starting."
assert r ==~ /(.*)(running|stopped|starting)\.?$/, "String should end with either running, started or stopped"
```

Explanation:

```
(.*) - matches anything
(running|stopped|starting) - matches either running, stopped or starting
\.? - optionally end with a dot expect zero or one occurrence of a dot, but you need to escape it, because the dot is a regex special character
$ - end of the line, so nothing should come after
```

the `==~` operator is the groovy [binary match operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_match_operator). This will return `true` if it matches, else `false`

See [this example](https://regex101.com/r/UVTKOu/1) on regex 101

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and links.  In the end, using '=~' instead of '==~' worked for me in the way i wanted to use this code

Comment: In your case the result is the same. However ‘=~‘ will return a regex object, which is `null` when there is no match. `assert null` will assert. Therefore it will work as well. Since you are not using the object you do not necessarily need the object. A Boolean will suffice. Don't know about performance and memory differences, although in this case they will be very small. The `==~` will return `true` on the first match and will therefor take the same time in the worst case.

Comment: But glad it helped. Regex101 is a great site if you want to validate regular expressions btw

Comment: Great explanation! You saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) does not receive String.

Try

```
Pattern.compile("your-regex").matcher("string-to-check").find()
```

Comment: That does require explicit approval. Otherwise it will fail:

org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.util.regex.Matcher find